# How can I install the latest Java?

Tags: java

I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 12.04. I opened Firefox and it says Java plug-in 1.7.0_13 is outdated and vulnerable.

I followed the link here for installing Java for Linux platforms: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml

I don't know what to do after this step:

"Unpack the tarball and install Java

```
tar zxvf jre-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

The Java files are installed in a directory called `jre1.7.0_07` in the current directory.
In this example, it is installed in the `/usr/java/jre1.7.0_07` directory.
Delete the `.tar.gz` file if you want to save disk space. "

Does this mean that it's installed? I don't think so, because I tried `java -version` in the Terminal and it says the old 1.7.0_13.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the instructions and its mentioned properly. Look at the 1st instruction

cd /usr/java/ but to do this you actually need to become as a root user. so modify it as

```
sudo cd /usr/java
```

Now move the downloaded file to `/usr/java` . so here you can use cp or mv but sudo is must.I mean

```
sudo cp <here path where you have downloaded the java file> .
```

dont forget the `.` in the above command because `.` will indicate current location.

so now you have copied ,downloaded java.tar to `/usr/java` location.
Then untar it

```
tar zxvf jre-7u7-linux-i586.tar.gz
```

Now configure your firefox. Uninstall previous Java add-on of firefox & close your firefox.

Now final step

Create a symbolic link to the libnpjp2.so file in the browser plugins directory

Go to the plugins sub-directory under the Firefox installation directory

```
cd <Firefox installation directory>/plugins
```

Create the symbolic link

```
ln -s <Java installation directory>/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
```

here this is your java installation directory.

```
/usr/java/jre1.7.0_07
```

after doing all the process successfully , just restart your system to apply the changes we made.

hope that it can help you.

Comment: Is it necessary to install Java to /usr/java?

Comment: No , If you dont have root access then you can do it in your home folder only and in that case your java installation directory will be ~/java/jre1.7.0_07

Comment: I do have root access. 

Before I posted here, I found a blog post which said to install to usr/lib/jvm. I moved the downloaded file there and unpacked it, but the Terminal still says the latest version is the old one.

Also, there's a lot of Java versions already there. Here's the contents:

java-6-sun      java-7-oracle  jre-7u25-linux-i586.tar.gz
java-6-sun-1.6.0.26  jre1.7.0_25

I'm confused. Should I just delete the other things there by moving them to Trash? And why isn't Terminal recognizing the new version?

Comment: The terminal can not give here because you are not installing java . your just using the java source. there is no problem with the new version.The only thing rightnow you have to focus is simply , is your firefox getting the java plug-in or not. :)

Comment: Should I delete the Java Sun/Oracle folders? Would that cause any problems with the system?

Comment: keep them . no problem we gonna face with them . sometimes they will have config files keep them

Comment: But Firefox says the old version is vulnerable. If I keep them, isn't that a vulnerability issue?

Also, I can't find a folder named plugins in the firefox directory. Should I just create one? Would it go inside the .mozilla folder or the profile folder?

Comment: thats why i told you to remove the old plug-in of the java.

Comment: I created the ln -s thing, but it shows up in the plugins folder with a lock on it. Does that mean I'd have to log in as root every time I use firefox to get it to work?

Comment: I can't delete the old version because I can't find one.

Comment: look at the link you did mentioned , there is a way for finding old one ?

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks for the help. I'd upvote your original suggestion, but it says I don't have enough points yet.

The plugins directory didn't exist in my firefox folder for some reason, so I couldn't follow what the link said. I finally got Java running by installing it and IcedTea through the Terminal's apt-get line.